# Illegal character (CTRL-CHAR, code 0) - Parsing Exception

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am currently running into

```
JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: (String)"    ){"BusinessDate"
```

It is because of the ')' before business date and there is four NUL before that, but they don't show up here as they are imaginary characters. That is the beginning of my json string I'm trying to map to my object. I'm just sending a ByteArray serialized as Avro, and trying to Deserialize using a ByteArray Deserializer (which I'm assuming is the problem). How do I get rid of those imaginary characters so it maps correctly to my object, or change my SCS consumer config to use Avro deserialization, only on that one consumer.

```
  // External topic listener
    @StreamListener(ChannelsScheduler.SCHEDULER_IN_FROM_EXTERNAL_EVENT)
    public void consumeMessage(@Payload GenericMessage<String> message) throws IOException
    {
        logger.info("Consumed message from external topic: {}", message);
```

I have tried

```
        GPTMStatus gptmStatus = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload(), GPTMStatus.class);
        GPTMStatus gptmStatus = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload().trim(), GPTMStatus.class);
        GPTMStatus gptmStatus = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload().replace(")", ""), GPTMStatus.class);


String json = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        GPTMStatus gptmStatus = mapper.readValue(json, GPTMStatus.class);
```

All three are receiving the same error as above.

Full Payload:

```
"    ){"BusinessDate":"2020-03-05","ContentUri":"20180712_EOB/1583443159984/0.xml","DFReference":"80712_EOB","DFRevision":0,"DFVersion":1583443159984}"
```

This is how I'm sending the message:

```
          kafka
              .send(
                  destination,
                  formatter.transform(df.getCanonicalPayload()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
              .get();
```

Comment: Could you add example `JSON` payload? I understand that your payload is a `String` - `message.getPayload().trim()`.

Comment: @MichałZiober Pretty much what I just posted, it is all valid json except there is like 3 or four "invisible" characters that I can't get rid of that come before the )

Answer (score 1):

This line is slightly misleading (at least to me)

`String json = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

JSON **CAN** contain the `NULL` control character but only if it's escaped and within a string field. I'd suggest starting with something simple, `json.replace("\0", "");` and checking if your code gets any further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will check that out, those are just the things I have tried that haven't worked.